# Best approach for unit-testing scoped viewmodels

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, android-viewmodel

When dealing with coroutines inside a viewModel is best to have said viewModel implement `CoroutineScope` so all coroutines are cancelled when the viewModel is cleared. Usually I see `coroutineContext` defined as `Dispatchers.Main + _job` so that coroutines are executed in the main UI thread by default. Usually this is done on a open class so that all your viewModels can extend it and get the scope without boilerplate code.

The issue arises when trying to unit test said viewModels as `Dispatchers.Main` is not available and trying to use it throws an exception. I am tryin to find a good solution that doesn't involve external libraries or too much boiler plate on the child viewModels.

My current solution is to add the maincontext as a contructor paramenter with the `Dispatchers.Main` as the default value. Then in the unit test, before testing the viewModel I set it to `Dispatchers.Default`. I don't quiet like this solution as it exposes the coroutineContext implementation details for everyone to see and change:

```
open class ScopedViewModel(var maincontext = Dispatchers.Main) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    private val _job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = maincontext + _job

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        _job.cancel()
    }
}
class MyViewModel : ScopedViewModel() {}
```

In the tests:

```
fun setup(){
    viewModel = MyViewModel()
    viewModel.maincontext = Dispacther.Default
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I copied a solution from RxJava2: if your test runs against RxJava2 flow which includes two or more different schedulers, you want, sure, all of them to actually run in a **single** thread.
Here is how it is done with RxJava2 testing:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void prepare() {
    RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
    RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
    RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
    RxJavaPlugins.setSingleSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
    RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
}
```

I did the same for coroutines. Just have created a class which collects dispatchers, but these dispatchers can be changed.

```
object ConfigurableDispatchers {

@JvmStatic
@Volatile
var Default: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default

@JvmStatic
@Volatile
var Main: MainCoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main

...
}
```

And, inside `@BeforeClass` method I call

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun setInstantMainDispatcher() {
    Main = object : MainCoroutineDispatcher() {
        @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
        override val immediate: MainCoroutineDispatcher
            get() = this

        override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
            block.run()
        }
    }
}
```

That will guarantee that the block will be executed in the calling thread.

It is the only alternative I found to constructor injection.

Comment: Given your `dispatch` implementation, you could return `this` from `immediate`.

Comment: Would just `Unconfined` work without a custom implementation?

Comment: If you mean `MainCoroutineDispatcher`, then worth mentioning that `Dispatchers.Unconfined` has a type of `CoroutineDispatcher`, whereas `MainCoroutineDispatcher` is a subtype of `CoroutineDispatcher`

Comment: I wonder if there's any need to statically expose that it's a `MainCoroutineDispatcher`. All its use sites will still accept it as a `CoroutineDispatcher`, then possibly use reflection to find out if it's more specific.

Comment: That is quite questionable. I wouldn't mess with the type, because it can change in  future or some specific dependency that will be involved in the application would want specifically `MainCoroutineDispatcher`. It doubt it exists without a reason, anyway

Comment: The type is there for a reason, that's for sure. It's an optimization measure. The only question is whether you gain anything by statically exposing it. Another point: `immediate` will never be used if you always return `true` from `isDispatchNeeded`.

Comment: I would be sure I gain nothing of it if I could investigate all both external and internal use sites of this dispatcher and see that specifics of this type is not used (I mean, `immediate`, for example), but it is quite impossible due to code generation for `Dispatchers` (opening `Unconfined` gives me a message `IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file. Implementation of methods is not available`). I did that just to keep myself safe from uses of the type in sites I haven't envisaged.

Comment: Actually, all you have to note is that the dispatcher is stored and accessed from the `CoroutineContext` using the `ContinuationInterceptor` key, therefore the framework retrieves it as that static type. Regarding `Unconfined`, in my project I do have access to the source code. It's a basic project with `kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8` as a dependency.

Comment: Do we need to use `runBlocking` when calling a method that uses coroutines from our test class? How does it work?

Comment: @KevinDesai, `runBlocking` blocks the invoking thread until the coroutines inside won't be completed.